# Appengine Error 400 while deploying bloog

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Recently i was deploying [bloog](https://github.com/DocSavage/bloog) a python based webblog on appengine but got this error

```
Uploading index definitions.
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Creating a composite index failed: This index:
entity_type: "Article"
ancestor: false
Property {
  name: "published"
  direction: 2
}
```

the content of index.yaml is

```
indexes:

- kind: Article
  properties:
  - name: __searchable_text_index
  - name: published
    direction: desc

- kind: Article
  properties:
  - name: article_type
  - name: published
    direction: desc

- kind: Article
  properties:
  - name: article_type
  - name: title

- kind: Article
  properties:
  - name: display_type
  - name: published
    direction: desc

- kind: Article
  properties:
  - name: published
    direction: desc

- kind: Article
  properties:
  - name: tags
  - name: published
    direction: desc

- kind: Comment
  properties:
  - name: article
  - name: thread

# AUTOGENERATED
```

so it fails to update index.yaml file, thus it gives 500 error on the main site , How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Delete that index - and any other single property indexes - from index.yaml. They're completely unnecessary, as single properties are already indexed by the datastore.